# Jquery select style editing

Tags: jquery

For my current project i am required to edit the default styles of a select element. Now normally i wouldnt bother but it's part of the design and lucky it's the only one on the whole site.

Now i'm trying out: https://github.com/scottdarby/Stylish-Select/ for the plugin to edit the styles. I've added my own custom sprite and thats fine. But im wondering, how would i go about, or is it possible to add a 'toggle' function to this easily?

If anyone can help , id really appreciate it.

#### EDIT

Here is the code im using: http://jsfiddle.net/TvqqN/12/ Perhaps toggle is the wrong description. I basically want to know if i can animate the showing of the list within the select?

Regards
M

Comment: some code and css would be helpful.

Comment: By toggle do you mean toggle the visibility of another object on change of the select value or do you mean toggle the visibility of the select itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the source code of stylish select to toggle the drop down with different animations (if you have jQuery UI) installed for example.

Find the line containingh `$containerDivWrapper.toggle();` and replace with `$containerDivWrapper.toggle("slow");` toggle it using the jQuery default linear swing transition.

Here is a version with jQuery UI included (via jsfiddle) and a 3s long easeInCirc transition:
http://jsfiddle.net/TvqqN/15/

Comment: Perfect, i can't believe i didn't see that. Thank you :)

Comment: No worries. Btw, stylish select is on github: https://github.com/scottdarby/Stylish-Select so if you make changes to support various animations via the configuration you can contribute back to the project.